# ASP.NET Web API Help Page with markdown comments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages, markdowndeep

I use [asp.net WebApi Help Page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage) to generate the document from comments of source code. And I have used [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to generate the document before. The [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can parse markdown syntax in the comments and output the well formatted documents. But the [WebApi Help Page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage) could not parse markdown syntax now.

For example, the `foo` function's comments contain *Markdown comments*, and it will be output as `### Markdown comments *It will return "foo" *It always returns "foo"` in [WebApi Help Page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage).

```
public MyApiController : ApiController {
     ///<summary>
     /// It will return "foo"
     /// ### Markdown comments
     /// * It will return "foo"
     /// * It always returns "foo"
     ///</summary>    
     [HttpPost, ActionName("foo")]
     public string Foo() {
         return "foo";
     }
}
```

Comment: I do not know about 'doxygen', but you could write your own implementation of `IDocumentationProvider` and supply it to HelpPage or you can take a look at the installed HelpPage file `Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs` and modify it as per your needs

Comment: I has read [IDocumentationProvider@MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.idocumentationprovider(v=vs.118).aspx), it returns 'string'. But the [MarkdownDeep](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MarkdownDeep.Full/1.5.0) make the `string` as input and turn it to `IHtmlString`.

Comment: Now, I modified the `Area\HelpPage\Views\DisplayTemplates`, and turn the `document` string to `@Html.Markdown(document).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the hints, have just modified `HelpPageApiModel.cshtml`

1) Install some Markdown library from NuGet, like `MarkdownDeep`

2) Add Helper function. Notice, you should trim lines, as `<summery>` is parsed as-is with all trailing whitespaces after newlines. Otherwise all markdown lists etc, wont be correctly parsed.

```
@functions {
    string ToMarkdown(string str)
    {
        var lines = str.Split('\n');
        var whitespaceCount = 0;
        var i = 0; //from 2. Line
        var imax = lines.Count();
        while (++i < imax)
        {
            var line = lines[i];
            if (whitespaceCount != 0)
            {
                lines[i] = line.Substring(whitespaceCount);
                continue;
            }
            var trimmed = line.TrimStart();
            if (trimmed.Length == 0 || trimmed == line) continue;
            whitespaceCount = line.Length - trimmed.Length;
            i--;
        }
        str = string.Join("\n", lines);
        var md = new MarkdownDeep.Markdown {ExtraMode = true, SafeMode = false};
        return md.Transform(str);
    }
}
```

3) Preprocess the documentation string output

```
<p>@Html.Raw(ToMarkdown(description.Documentation))</p>
```

Comment: I cannot verify this answer. So I give an up vote first. Now, I don't write C# codes, and asp.net MVC codes anymore. So, I cannot verify this answer.

Comment: I have verified this answer and its awesome. I see now why all the extra trimming of white space is necessary after I've tested it out. thanks saved my day.